# Generating pairs of elements from array in C++

Tags: c++

If I have an array of elements for example:

```
int array[10] = {2,3,4,5,7}
```

What would be the fastest way to generate elements which have same difference?
for example:

if difference = 1
then elements are 2,3
if difference = 2
the pairs are (3,5) and (5,7)
and so on for all the differences

I haven't taken any algorithm courses and I know only C++ language.

Comment: Is the array sorted?  If so, you can walk through it with two iterators.  You move the right-hand one if the difference is too small, and the left-hand one if the difference is too big.  If the difference is the one you want, you move both.

Comment: I agree with paddy. In fact even if it wasn't sorted, sorting (with a O(nlgn) sort) and then applying this algorithm would still be faster than brute force search of all possible pairs. Edit: for sort check http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/

Comment: Can you also clarify your description?  You said for difference=1, elements are (2,3), but you did not mention (3,4) or (4,5).  Likewise for difference=2, where you omitted (2,4).  Is there some other rule that you didn't tell us, or was that just a mistake?

Comment: Oh sorry!!
All the possible pairs have to be generated.Can I use this iterator for an array?

Comment: By 'iterator', I just mean 'array index'.  Run the algorithm until the right-hand iterator (index) goes past the last element.

Comment: "iterator" can also mean "pointer into the array". Note that you have 5 `0`s at the end, so it's not sorted (but the sub-sequence `[array, array+5)` *is*)

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){

        int a[] =  {2,3,4,5,7};
        int n = 5;
        int d = 2;
        for(int i = 0;i<n-1;i++){
           for(int j = i+1;j<n;j++){
              if(abs(a[i]-a[j])==d)
              cout<<"(" <<(a[i])<<", "<<(a[j])<<"), ";
           }
        }

    return 0;
}
```